# Solution for Linear SDE with 2-dimentional noise and static coefficients

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I need to find solutions for SDE of types:
$$
dX_t=a\,dt+b^1\,dW_t^1+b^2\,dW_t^2\\
dX_t=a\,dt+b^1\,dW_t^1+b^2\,X_t\,dW_t^2
$$

As far I've found solutions for SDE with 2-dimensional noise in an amazing book of P. Kloeden - *Numerical Solution  For Stochastic Differential Equations*.

It has a solution for this type of equation:
$$
dX_t=aX_t\,dt+b^1X_t\,dW_t^1+b^2X_t\,dW_t^2\\
X_t=X_0\exp\Biggl(\Biggl(a-\frac12((b^1)^2+(b^2)^2)\Biggr)t+b^1W_t^1+b^2W_t^2\Biggr)
$$

Is there some generic solution for SDE with 2-dimensional noise like for the General Linear SDE?
Maybe it is possible to use the upper solution here?

UPDATE:
As [lutzl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115115/lutzl) proposed, the first equation can be reduced to this type:
$$dX_t=adt+\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}dW_t$$
Where:
$$X_t=at+\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}W_t$$
Is it correct?

Comment: You have $b^1W^1_t+b^2W^2_t=\sqrt{(b^1)^2+(b^2)^2}\tilde W$ where $\tilde W$ is itself a Brownian motion. Thus the first and third problem are essentially with one-dimensional noise, the third reduces to the standard geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: You can also integrate the first directly, $X_t=X_0+at+b^1\,W^1_t+b^2\,W^2_t$. Note the integration constant.